# Cannot convert value of type 'org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient'

Tags: maven

In one XML configuration file I have this bean which is a property of an other bean :

```
 <bean class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient">
```

In my pom.xml I added these two dependencies because I needed both :

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
     <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
     <version>3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
  <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
  <version>4.3.5</version>
</dependency>
```

When I deploy my EAR in Websphere server I have this error :

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient' to required type 'org.apache.http.client.HttpClient' for property 'httpClient': no matching editors or conversion strategy found

So in my pom.xml I added

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
           <phase>package</phase>
           <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
           </goals>
           <configuration>
              <filters>
                 <filter>                                          
                 <artifact>org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient</artifact>
              <excludes>                                                
                <exclude>org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.class</exclude>
              </excludes>
                 </filter>
              </filter>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
       </executions>
   </plugin>
```

After the compilation I noticed that it totally changed the structure of the WAR embedded in the EAR. I don't find other solutions